# How to prepare training set for Support vector regression model which is able able to include the rows until row number 1000?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have the data frame i.e. df. Which has more than `2000 rows` and `15 columns` including `expense column`.  I have completed all of the processes for SVR. Now I want to make the training set to include the rows until row number 1000.

The test set will have one single row, row number `1001`.

For preparing the training and testing the model I need to take the `expense column` as the target value and all other columns will be taken as the features.

But I know the method for splitting it into training(50%) and testing set(50%). Which I included below:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVR
import pandas
import sklearn
csv = pandas.read_csv('data.csv')
train, test = sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split(csv, train_size = 0.5)
```

If I prepare the training and testing set as above mention, how may I write code?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
csv = pandas.read_csv('data.csv')
train, test = csv.loc[:1000], csv.loc[1001]
```

To then split the train test sets further into X and Y, simply do:

```
train_X, train_Y = train.drop(columns=['expense']), test['expense']
test_X, test_Y = train.drop(columns=['expense']), test['expense']
```

If instead you want to use the column 'use' as a response, the following should work:

```
train, test = dataset.loc[:1000], dataset.loc[1001]

train_X, train_y = train.drop(columns=['use']), train['use']
test_X, test_y = test.drop(columns=['use']), test['use']

SupportVectorRefModel = SVR()
SupportVectorRefModel.fit(train_X, train_y)
SupportVectorRefModel.predict(test_X)
```

Comment: `from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split`
`from sklearn.svm import SVR`

#`X = dataset.loc[:1000]`
#`y = dataset.loc[1001]`

Comment: I updated my answer such that it also includes splitting X and Y.

Comment: I know replaced df.loc[...] with of csv.loc[...] to my code. Let me know if it works this way.

Comment: If this is your full code, then obviously test is not defined since you never defined it. Why don't you do it as I suggested? I am quite sure it works.

Comment: `train_X, train_Y = train.drop(columns=['expense']), test['expense']
test_X, test_Y = train.drop(columns=['expense']), test['expense']`

This line seems that the `expense column` is dropped from entire dataset.

But I need to drop them from the variables which are obtained in the previous lines. So it needs to use the variables "X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test" in lines 247 and 248 appropriately. Could you give instructions for these purposes?

Comment: I am sorry but I don't quite understand your question. What my code does it first splits the entire data frame into a training and test data and then splits both of them further into predictors and response. I updated my answer in response to your second question below.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of proving enough information.

`train_X, train_Y = train.drop(columns=['expense']), test['expense'] test_X, test_Y = train.drop(columns=['expense']), test['expense']`

if I use this it is going like that `expense column` is going to remove from the entire dataset. But I need to drop them from the variables which are obtained in the previous lines i.e.

 `X = dataset.loc[:1000] 
 y = dataset.loc[1001] `. 

So it needs to use the variables "X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test" within the above lines appropriately.

Comment: I think there is some confusion about train vs. test. set and X vs. Y. Be careful! Your code `test_X, test_Y = train.drop(columns=['expense']), test['expense']` should use the test set, not the train set. Also, `X = dataset.loc[:1000]` and  `y = dataset.loc[1001]` gives you the train and test sets but not X and Y.

Comment: Thanks for Your kind response. I am writing code as the below way 

`#from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split from sklearn.svm import SVR #X_train, y_train = dataset.loc[:1000], dataset.loc[:1000] 
#X_test, y_test   = dataset.loc[1001], dataset.loc[1001] 

#train_X, train_y = dataset.drop(columns=['expense']), y_test['expense']
#test_X, test_y = dataset.drop(columns=['expense']), X_test['expense']`

It has shown an error: `ValueError: bad input shape (977, 58)`

Comment: @Mr.Asif Please do **not** use the comments space for providing such chunks of code - it is literally unreadable! Comments are also not the place for perpetual follow-up questions; I kindly suggest you start from a clean slate - open a **new question** with the new situation and issues (you can include a link to this one, or ping also the respondent here for the new question).

Comment: Thanks for your kind response. I am going to open a new question.

Comment: Could anyone help to solve the below problem? This is the link of my other post.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61858952/how-to-prepare-training-and-test-set-for-support-vector-regression-model-svr-w